# andorid daydream service webview (context requires the flag_activity_new_task flag)

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-service, android-context

I have implemented the android daydream service in which I have played a video from asserts ,
I have put a button there and onclick listener I want to open a webview with a link, every things goes right but I can't able to deal with the webview as when I clicks the button this message appear

**Unfortunatley App has stopped**

and the error message that appears in log is

> **AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: 
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  con text requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?**

I have created the webview in the xml file

my code for calling webview is:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Perform action on click   
           vv.stopPlayback();
           vv.setVisibility(View.GONE);//for media player

           webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search i found answer of my question here is the link that helps me most

[link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/screensavers/WebView/+/master/src/com/android/dreams/web)

basically i just put this class code in my android dreamservice

```
    private class LinkLauncher extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```

and uses the webview as follow

```
           WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
           webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           webview.setWebViewClient(new LinkLauncher());

           WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
           webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

           webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

i write answer that might help anyone else.
thanks

Comment: You don't even need to implement a custom WebViewClient.
Just setting up an empty WebViewClient on the WebView would have solved the problem (yes, that's surprising :) ).